# Python: Insert a column of lists to Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, list, sql-insert, series

I have a data(results) that looks like this:

[a column of lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHxHP.png)

I would like to insert the data frame to a Mysql table (alarm):

What i have done so far:

```
session = Session()

for _, row in results_1.iterrows():
    
    insert_stmt = f"insert into alarm (service) values ({row['service']}) ;"

    session.execute(insert_stmt)

session.commit()
session.close

## insert to mysql
```

DB_import_ref(db_table_name)

This keeps sending the error:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['CS5', 'BE'])' at line 1")
```

Plz any help to insert a column of lists to Mysql ?

Comment: Seriously consider whether you really want to store a list in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You get a list, that has tio be converted to a string first before you enter it.

But  you should take a god look at [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) and reconsider your approach

```
for _, row in results_1.iterrows():

    str1 = ''.join(row['service'])
    
    insert_stmt = f"insert into alarm (service) values ({}) ;".format(str1)

    session.execute(insert_stmt)
```